# XML response to NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, arrays

I parse a xml file to get the content of two nodes "tagid" and "mac".
How can I store this content in two arrays, one for "tagid" and one for "mac"?

The "parser" works. Thank you in advance

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.currentElement = elementName;
    self.currentElement2 = elementName;

    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
        self.currentTitle = [NSMutableString string];

    }

    if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
        self.currentTitle2 = [NSMutableString string];

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle);
    }

    if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle2);
    }

    self.currentTitle = nil;
    self.currentElement = nil;
    self.currentTitle2 = nil;
    self.currentElement2 = nil;

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if (!self.currentElement) return;
    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
        self.currentTitle = string;

    }

    if (!self.currentElement2) return;
    if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
        self.currentTitle2 = string;
    }

}
- (IBAction)aktualisieren:(id)sender {

    NSURL *xmlURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://mysite/mycontent"];

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

Thank you for your responses :)

Comment: [XML-to-Dictinary converter](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two different arrays

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

self.currentElement = elementName;
self.currentElement2 = elementName;

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
    self.currentTitle = [NSMutableString string];
    NSMutableArray *macArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
    self.currentTitle2 = [NSMutableString string];
    NSMutableArray *tagIdArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle);
    [macArray addObject:self.currentTitle];
}

if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle2);
    [tagIdArray addObject:self.currentTitle2];
}

self.currentTitle = nil;
self.currentElement = nil;
self.currentTitle2 = nil;
self.currentElement2 = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

create two arrays in `parseStartDocument`. one for mac-MacArray , one for tagid-tagArray.

in `didEndElement` method,check for element & add your `self.currentTitle` to that perticular your Array.

Answer (score 3):

In .h declare two arrays tagArray and macArray.
In viewDidLoad alloc init both arrays.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
    [macArray addObject:self.currentTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle);
}

if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
    [macArray addObject:self.currentTitle2];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle2);
}

self.currentTitle = nil;
self.currentElement = nil;
self.currentTitle2 = nil;
self.currentElement2 = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare two mutable arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *macArray , *tagidArray;

macArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tagidArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
[macArray addObject:self.currentTitle];
NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle);
}

if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
[tagidArray addObject:self.currentTitle2];
NSLog(@"%@", self.currentTitle2);
}

}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument{

//Do something as parsing has been completed here and your values are in two arrays
}
```

Find detailed parsing example [here](http://blackberrymastercracks.blogspot.in)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if either of these was a long string, might get separated into multiple calls to `foundCharacters`. Thus, `foundCharacters` should always append strings, not setting strings:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if (!self.currentElement) return;
    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"mac"]) {
        [self.currentTitle appendString:string];
    }

    if (!self.currentElement2) return;
    if ([self.currentElement2 isEqualToString:@"tagid"]) {
        [self.currentTitle2 appendString:string];
    }
}
```